# How to update specific object value of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of objects, I did a map on that array now I want to change specific object values. I used `onChange` method inside `map()` function. It not working properly could someone please help me to achieve this problem solution.

thanks

```
localPreRoutingCall &&
    localPreRoutingCall.map((item, index) => (
      <>
        <div className="pre-route-title">{item && item.field_title}</div>
        <textarea
          placeholder="Enter something"
          className="pre-route-textarea"
          value={item && item.value}
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.persist();
            changeObjectValue(e.target.value, item);
          }}
        />
        <div className="pre-route-description">
          {item && item.description}
        </div>
      </>
    ))
```

**A function where I am updating object value**

```
 const changeObjectValue = (value, item) => {
    console.log("@@ array", value);
    let localArray = localPreRoutingCall;
    var index = _.findIndex(localArray, { id: item.id });
    localArray.splice(index, 1, { ...item, value: value });
    setLocalPreRoutingCall(localArray);
  };
```

Comment: Can you try to provide `key` property to map the content container?

Comment: I tried but I am sorry I was not able to achieve my goal. when I type something in textarea it just updates a single character as I type `Jonas` it just updated `S` not like full name

Comment: so you should also try to do `{...item, value: oldValue + value}`

Comment: actually, when I type name as `Jonas` it re-render component 5 time and it just return single character on each render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like said in the comments, you have to pass a `key` prop to what you're rendering so React knows what changes.

I don't see a reason for you to use the `e.persist` function when you're passing the value immediately.

```
import { Fragment } from "react";

localPreRoutingCall?.map((item, i) => (
  <Fragment key={item.id}>
    <div className="pre-route-title">{item.field_title}</div>
    <textarea
      placeholder="Enter something"
      className="pre-route-textarea"
      value={item.value}
      onChange={(e) => changeObjectValue(e.target.value, i)}
    />
    <div className="pre-route-description">
      {item.description}
    </div>
  </Fragment>
))
```

You also didn't clone the `localPreRoutingCall` state array before changing its value.

Another reason why React won't know what changed.

```
const changeObjectValue = (value, i) => {
  const localArray = [...localPreRoutingCall];
  localArray[i].value = value;
  setLocalPreRoutingCall(localArray);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem I can see is that you aren't giving the mapped components keys.

`<>` can't be used in map because it can't be passed a key, so this would be an improvement

```
<React.Fragment key={item.id}>
```

Comment: I tried but I am sorry I was not able to achieve my goal. when I type something in textarea it just updates a single character as I type `Jonas` it just updated `S`, not like full name

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

> localArray.splice(index, 1, { ...item, value: value });

Use

localArray[index].value = value

Comment: Actually, It just updates the last character of the entered text. I want to store full text

Comment: Find what you are getting from "e.target.value ". If it only last character then you need to concat it with the previous value

Comment: I need some help in code, could you please share some code how can I achieve it